# Xcode how to access UIView from an external class

Tags: ios, xcode, class, uinavigationbar

From the view controller I can style the navigationBar by calling this method:

```
- (void)styleNavigationViewController {
    [[self.navigationController.navigationBar.subviews objectAtIndex:0] setAlpha:0.0f];
}
```

I'm using this on several views so I'd like to put it in a separate class file and just include/call when needed.

What would that method look like on an external class? how can I reference 'self'?

Answer (score 0):

Method 1. Add this method to your baseViewController if you have one

Method 2. Add a category to `UIViewController` and import that category whenever you need this method

Answer (score 0):

Any reason an alternative like this wouldn't work?

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setAlpha: 0.0];
```

If that doesn't work, I must ask, why do you need to hide some (if not all) navigation bars?